# How to determine Shortest Path is considered as P (Polynomial Time) class problem?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What are the P class Problem and how to verified the problem is P class problem?

How to prove that shortest path is P class problem?

Answer (score 1):

To show a problem is in P (Polynomial time), you need to show there is an efficient (polynomial time) solution to solve the problem.